# usar if no sql server

Tags: sql, if

Tenho 3 tabelas no meu banco de dados, CLIENTES, DISTRIBUIDORES e EXPORTAÇÃO  e tenho uma tabela de ordem de produção onde pego o tipo de cliente (Distribuidor, cliente ou exportação) e o ID de cada deles . a duvida é: tem como eu colocar um `if` no `select`, pra poder juntar as 3 tabelas com a de ordem de produção? tipo assim:

```
if (tipocliente == CLIENTE)
    select CamposDaTabela from OrdemDeProduçao inner join Cliente
if (tipocliente == Distribuidor)
    select select CamposDaTabela from OrdemDeProduçao inner join Distribuidor
if (tipocliente == exportaçao)
    select CamposDaTabela from OrdemDeProduçao inner join Exportaçao
```

Teria como fazer assim dentro do sql mesmo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem a questão, mas vamos lá.

Você poderia fazer 3 `SELECTS` e usar `UNION` pra retornar tudo de uma vez, assim:

```
SELECT CamposDaTabela, CampoCliente 
  FROM OrdemDeProduçao 
 INNER JOIN Cliente ON ...
 WHERE tipocliente = cliente

 UNION 

SELECT CamposDaTabela, CampoDistribuidor 
  FROM OrdemDeProduçao 
 INNER JOIN Distribuidor ON ...
 WHERE tipocliente = distribuidor

UNION 

SELECT CamposDaTabela, CampoExportacao 
  FROM OrdemDeProduçao  
 INNER JOIN Exportaçao ON ...
 WHERE tipocliente = exportacao

UNION

SELECT CamposDaTabela, NULL AS CampoNulo // ou substitua por 0, ou string vazia, dependendo do tipo de dados nas outras selects...
  FROM OrdemDeProduçao  
 WHERE tipocliente = NULL
```

Comment: opa Emerson era exatamente isso mesmo... mas agora um outro probleminha... pode acontecer de o tipocliente for nulo ... tem como exibir os nulos tbm??

Comment: Sim, basta fazer mais uma SELECT, acrescentar ela com UNION. Neste caso, como o tipo do cliente é NULL ,você não fará JOIN com nenhuma tabela. Vou editar minha resposta pra contemplar este caso.

Comment: Resposta alterada, verifique.

Comment: bom eu tentei aqui e deu essa mensagem: 
Mensagem 205, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que as 4 selects devem retornar o mesmo número de campos. Inclusive, estes campos tem que ser do mesmo tipo de dados. Senão você não consegue usar o UNION. Se não conseguir corrigir o erro altere sua questão e coloque a nova SELECT para facilitar.

Comment: é pq no select do null fica um campo a menos pelo fato de nao juntar com outra... teria como eu criar um campo vazio na hr do select só pra ficar igual??

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41010/discussion-between-douglas-and-emerson-js).

Comment: Resposta editada com a adição do campo nulo na última SELECT. Poderia também ser uma string vazia, ou um 0, dependendo do tipo de dados usado nas outras 3 SELECTS. Verifique.

Comment: ahhh deu certinho ... vlw msm cara obrigado de vdd

Answer (score 3):

**De uma forma resumida**: 
Você pode usar a função `CASE`:

```
SELECT CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y' 
                     THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
             END AS bit) as Saleable, * 
FROM Product
```

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select) tem vários exemplos e explicacoes.

Answer (score 3):

**ELSE (IF...ELSE) (Transact-SQL)**

Impõe condições na execução de uma instrução `Transact-SQL`. A instrução `Transact-SQL (sql_statement)` que segue a `Boolean_expression` será executada se a `Boolean_expression` for avaliada como `TRUE`. A palavra-chave opcional `ELSE` é uma instrução `Transact-SQL` alternativa que é executada quando a `Boolean_expression` for avaliada como `FALSE` ou `NULL`.

**Argumentos**

> Boolean_expression

É uma expressão que retorna TRUE ou FALSE. Se a Boolean_expression contiver uma instrução SELECT, esta deverá ser incluída entre parênteses.

> { sql_statement | statement_block }

É qualquer instrução Transact-SQL ou agrupamento de instruções válido, conforme definido com um bloco de instruções. Para definir um bloco de instruções (lote), use as palavras-chave BEGIN e END da linguagem de controle de fluxo. Embora todas as instruções Transact-SQL sejam válidas em um bloco BEGIN...END, certas instruções Transact-SQL não devem ser agrupadas no mesmo lote (bloco de instrução).

```
SET @Number = 50;
IF @Number > 100
   PRINT 'The number is large.';
ELSE 
   BEGIN
      IF @Number < 10
      PRINT 'The number is small.';
   ELSE
      PRINT 'The number is medium.';
   END ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da forma que esta fazendo, a unica diferença é que no sql você só usa um **=** para comparar.

```
declare @tipocliente int = 3, @CLIENTE int = 1, @Distribuidor int = 2, @exportaçao int = 3

if (@tipocliente = @CLIENTE)
print 'select CamposDaTabela from OrdemDeProduçao inner join Cliente'
if (@tipocliente = @Distribuidor)
print ' select select CamposDaTabela from OrdemDeProduçao inner join Distribuidor'
if (@tipocliente = @exportaçao)
print 'select CamposDaTabela from OrdemDeProduçao inner join Exportaçao'
```

Answer (score 0):

Então pessoal...

a partir da versão [2012](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) do SQL Server, passou a ser possível utilizar o "in line if"

IIF(expressão, valor_se_verdadeiro, valor_se_falso)

Obviamente as soluções já apresentadas dariam um melhor suporte/garantia ao programador, porque funcionariam mesmo em versões mais antigas do SQL Server.